# AngularJS html5mode page refresh not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, .htaccess

I have enabled html5mode in my angularjs project and it is working fine but when I refresh a page I only get the partial view without the index.html code. I have tried alot of things but nothing seems to work.

**Folder Structure**

index.html

app.js

.htaccess

/home

-- home.html

-- home.js

**index.html**

```
<base href="/">
```

**app.js**

```
.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
  $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/home'});
  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!');
})
```

**home.js**

```
.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/home', {
    templateUrl: '/home/home.html',
    controller: 'HomeCtrl'
  });
})
```

**.htaccess**

```
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index
    RewriteRule (.*) index.html [L]
</ifModule>
```

Comment: don't name routes in angular that match real server routes

Comment: Of course! Thank you so much.

Comment: Do you got any solutions for this. we are also facing same refresh issue in ubuntu apache server.